# How do you return an array from a C DLL to .NET via a parameter?

Tags: c#, c, .net, dll

I want to return 2 arrays from a C DLL to a C# program. Returning one array as a return value seems to be no problem. But if I want to return a second array via an out parameter, it always seems to return a null pointer. Here's the DLL function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double* Test(double* paramArray)
{
    paramArray = new double[100];
    // populate paramArray
    double* returnArray = new double[100];
    // populate returnArray
    return returnArray;
}
```

And here's the C# code (please ignore the lack of freeing the memory allocated in the DLL for simplicity):

```
[DllImport("Dll.dll")]
static extern IntPtr Test(out IntPtr paramArray);

static double[] TestWrapper(out double[] array)
{
    IntPtr ret_data_pointer = Test(out IntPtr param_data_pointer);
    array = new double[100];
    Marshal.Copy(param_data_pointer, array, 0, array.Length);
    double[] ret_data = new double[100];
    Marshal.Copy(ret_data_pointer, ret_data, 0, ret_data.Length);
    return ret_data;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] ret_array = TestWrapper(out double[] param_array);
}
```

I have gotten it to work by returning a struct with a pointer to both arrays, but I would prefer the more straightforward approach using a return value and an out parameter.

Comment: Your C code is broken. To return a value via a parameter, you need to pass a pointer to the variable that will accept the value. Since you want to return a pointer via a parameter, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer (`double**`).

Comment: You need something like this: Test(double** paramArray) { *paramArray = new double[100]; ... }

Comment: CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl is missing from the attribute.  Don't forget that somebody is going to have to call delete[] again, that can't be the C# code.

Comment: Thanks ikegami and OptionalOption, that was it. If one of you want to make it into an answer I'll accept it.